# How to be sure that all documents indexed in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have a question about [Index Aliases and Zero Downtime](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html)
When we put a document to an index it takes time until document available for search.

How to check that all documents available for search before switching from old to a new index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to get that information is to get the stats of the index (`GET your-index/_stats/docs,indexing`) and compare the stats of the `docs` and `indexing` blocks.

```
...
"_all" : {
  "primaries" : {
    "docs" : {
      "count" : 1234,     <-- searchable docs
       "deleted" : 0
    },
    "indexing" : {
      "index_total" : 1300,      <--- indexed docs
      "index_time_in_millis" : 13,
      ...
    }
...
```

To make all your docs searchable, you can either wait for your refresh strategy to kick in, or you trigger an index refresh explicitly by using the refresh API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/indices-refresh.html)

Comment: `indexing.index_total` can be greater than `docs.count` because when we update document `indexing.index_total` will be incremented